# How to join two solr indexes and get result from both?

Tags: search, solr, lucene

I have two indices, on two different cores:

```
firstCore {id, fid, resid, status}
secondCore {id, resid, title, name, cat, role, exp}
```

I want to execute a join query that will give result of both the indexes, with matching criteria, I mean to display `id, fid, resid, status, title, name, cat, role, exp`. We can omit `id`, if needed, and this is `id` of `secondCore`.
What I tried:
1. Following query returned: `id, fid, resid, status` i.e. of `firstCore`

```
 http://localhost:8888/solr/firstCore/select?q=*:*&fq={!join from=resid to=resid fromIndex=secondCore}resid:546384
```

2. Following query returned: `id, resid, title, name, cat, role, exp`, i.e. of `secondCore`.

   `http://localhost:8888/solr/secondCore/select?q=*:*&fq={!join%20from=resid%20to=resid%20fromIndex=firstCore}resid:546384`

How can I get, `id, fid, resid, status, title, name, cat, role, exp`?

Comment: Hi, do you solve this now?Thanks

Comment: No. Couldn't get to solution.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by sharding but as of now there is no solution for this.

This might help, check out http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/lucene-solr-user/201510.mbox/%3CCAEYSxhVie4oei+7sMFuAEZgOUxbJ-YM_hzHh54kgWiPqJuoFhQ@mail.gmail.com%3E